# Accept an array, erase some elements and print the array

Tags: c++, object-oriented, static

I'm trying to learn about OOP, specifically encapsulation, and use of static.

My goal is to improve my coding skills, I am just looking for feedback specific to **encapsulation**, the use of **static**, and any other tips to make this **"production quality"**. I don't feel confident the Solve method has been implemented correctly. By instantiating the object its contained within. Similarly the call to solve in main.

The question was very simple (accept an array, erase some elements and print the array) and very specific about the format of data.

> Given the size of a vector, its elements, an element to delete, and a range of elements to delete, after the first delete operation. Perform the deletes, and return the size of the array and its contents.

Input:

```
6
1 4 6 2 8 9
2
2 4
```

Output:

```
3
1 8 9
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class File {
    int size = 0;
    int eraseStart = 0;
    int eraseEnd = 0;
    int eraseEle = 0;
    std::vector<int> v;
    
public:
    const std::vector<int> getVect() { return v; }
    const int getStart() { return eraseStart; }
    const int getEnd() { return eraseEnd; }
    const int getEraseEle() { return eraseEle; }

    void processData() {
        int temp = 0;
        std::cin >> size;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            std::cin >> temp;
            v.push_back(temp);
        }
        std::cin >> eraseEle;
        std::cin >> eraseStart >> eraseEnd;
        return;
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << size << '\n';
        for (auto x : v) {
            std::cout << x << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        return;
    }

    void erase1(int i) {
        v.erase(v.begin() + i - 1);
        size--;
        return;
    }

    void eraseRange(int start, int end) {
        v.erase(v.begin() + start - 1, v.begin() + end - 1);
        size -= end - start;
        return;
    }

    static void solve() {
        File file;
        file.processData();
        file.erase1(file.getEraseEle());
        file.eraseRange(file.getStart(), file.getEnd());
        file.print();
        return;
    }
};

int main() {
    File::solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/276891/revisions#rev-body-ac7dbc64-8c6d-4dbc-8cd2-83828171f141) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: Is the problem statement a programming challenge on some site, or did you find it in a book?

Comment: The problem statement is a shortened version of https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/vector-erase/problem?isFullScreen=true
I decided to over engineer it as practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues you are interested in are deep, deep issues of software design and idiomatic C++. There’s no “right” answer, and different C++ experts will have different opinions about what the “best” solution would look like.

So, there’s just no possible way I can give an answer that isn’t at least partially coloured by my own biases. Please keep that in mind.

I’d start a design review by suggesting a top-down approach: start with what you think a really good solution should look like, and then figure out the details.

So, okay, what would a really good solution look like. Would it look like `File::solve();`? I’d say no.

What’s wrong with `File::solve();`? Well:

1. It’s utterly meaningless. If you saw `File::solve();` in someone else’s program, what would you think? What is that line doing? What does it mean?
2. It’s completely inflexible. Whatever `File::solve();` does, it clearly doesn’t give the user any say in how, when, or where it’s doing it. As a user, I chafe at the idea that the person who wrote that function thinks they know more than I do about what I want or need.
3. It’s literal nonsense: How do you “solve” a file?

The name `solve()` isn’t really the problem; the issue is that there is no good explanation of *what* is being solved, or how. The real problem here is `File`. This class does not describe a file, and even if it did, that is not what any of this is really *about*.

So `File` is a terrible name. What would be a good name? Well, what is the class actually *about*? It’s about some kind of challenge, it seems. So, maybe a name like `array_modification_problem` (or `ArrayModificationProblem`, if you prefer; I just find [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) easier to read). That would give you `array_modification_problem::solve()`… which, to me, is a *lot* clearer, and even reads better. If I saw that in code, I would immediately understand that there is some problem involving modifying arrays, and this line is solving it. Which, while vague, is correct.

There’s still a problem, though… well, half of a problem. The solver is completely inflexible. You can’t control anything about it. What if you don’t want to read the data from `std::cin`? What if you want to read it from a file instead? And what if you don’t want to write the results to `std::cout`?

There’s another important reason to give this flexibility: testing. You should ***ALWAYS*** test your code. In fact, you should write tests for your code, **before you write the code**. Code without tests is garbage code; I won’t accept code without tests in any projects I’m in charge of. The *best* thing you can learn as a coder, is how to ***PROPERLY*** test your code.

If you hard-code `std::cin` and `std::cout` into your solver, you make it *extremely* difficult to test. If you take the input and output streams as arguments, then you make it easy to test. For example:

```
class array_modification_problem
{
public:
    static auto solve(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out)
    {
        // actual solution here
    }

    static auto solve()
    {
        return solve(std::cin, std::cout);
    }

    // ...
};

// Example of how to test, using Catch2:
TEST_CASE("example case")
{
    constexpr auto example_input = R"(6
1 4 6 2 8 9
2
2 4
)";
    constexpr auto example_output = R"(3
1 8 9
)";

    auto in  = std::istringstream{example_input};
    auto out = std::ostringstream{};

    array_modification_problem::solve(in, out);

    REQUIRE(out.str() == example_output);
}
```

Note that I’ve included an overload that defaults the input and output streams to `std::cin` and `std::cout`, so you can still do `array_modification_problem::solve();` as a shorthand for `array_modification_problem::solve(std::cin, std::cout);`.

See how being able to provide your own streams as input and output makes testing easy? We simply create a string stream, fill it with the example input, run the solver, and then check that the expected results were written to the output string stream. Easy peasy. If you had no way to specify the streams, this would become *incredibly* hard.

But let’s go a step further. Because maybe we don’t want to just *print* the results. Maybe we might want the final vector. We might want to do a more complex problem of which this problem is only a sub-step.

So in addition to the two `solve()` functions above, I’d also suggest one that takes an input stream, and just *returns* the final vector:

```
class array_modification_problem
{
public:
    static auto solve(std::istream& in)
    {
        // read the data from in

        // solve the problem

        // return the final vector
    }

    static auto solve(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out)
    {
        auto result = solve(in);

        // write result to out
    }

    static auto solve()
    {
        return solve(std::cin, std::cout);
    }

    // ...
};
```

This makes the solver much more flexible, and as a bonus, it makes testing even easier.

But we can go even further!

Consider the problem. The input data to the problem is a vector, a single number, then a pair of numbers. So… why not actually code a function that just takes that directly?

```
    static auto solve(std::vector<int> data, int position, std::pair<int, int> range)
    {
        data.erase(data.begin() + (position - 1));
        data.erase(data.begin() + (std::get<0>(range) - 1), data.begin() + (std::get<1>(range) - 1));
        return data;
    }
```

All other functions can now be written in terms of this function. You just need two helpers:

```
    static auto read(std::istream& in)
    {
        // this is basically your processData() function

        // read the data vector, the position, and then the two range numbers

        return std::tuple{data, position, std::tuple{start, end}};
    }

    static auto write(std::vector<int> const& data, std::ostream& out)
    {
        // this is basically your print() function
    }
```

And now everything else is easy:

```
    static auto solve(std::istream& in)
    {
        auto [data, position, range] = read(in);

        return solve(std::move(data), position, range);
    }

    static auto solve(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out)
    {
        write(solve(in), out);
    }

    static auto solve()
    {
        return solve(std::cin, std::cout);
    }
```

So, so far, the interface of the class looks like this:

```
class array_modification_problem
{
public:
    // Input/output functions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    // Read problem data from stream.
    static auto read(std::istream& in) -> std::tuple<std::vector<int>, int, std::tuple<int, int>>;

    // Write solution to stream.
    static auto write(std::vector<int> const& data, std::ostream& out) -> void;

    // Actual solution function ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    static auto solve(std::tuple<std::vector<int>, int, std::tuple<int, int>> problem_data) -> std::vector<int>;

    // Nicer interface functions to simplify the above ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    static auto solve(std::istream& in) -> std::vector<int>;
    static auto solve(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) -> void;
    static auto solve() -> void;
};
```

I’d say that’s a pretty decent interface. It’s easy to use. And so long as you pass legal values, it’s pretty darn hard to misuse.

But now we get to the part that you’re really interested in. Note that in the interface about, I use this large tuple type twice:

```
std::tuple<std::vector<int>, int, std::tuple<int, int>>
```

That tuple type is the problem data: the vector, the position for the single removal, and then the range for the range removal. While using a tuple for this works, it’s kind of ugly. So what if we instead use the actual problem class to store the problem data (as you did):

```
class array_modification_problem
{
public:
    // Input/output functions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    // Read problem data from stream.
    static auto read(std::istream& in) -> array_modification_problem;

    // Write solution to stream.
    static auto write(std::vector<int> const& data, std::ostream& out) -> void;

    // Actual solution function ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    static auto solve(array_modification_problem const& problem_data) -> std::vector<int>;

    // Nicer interface functions to simplify the above ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    static auto solve(std::istream& in) -> std::vector<int>;
    static auto solve(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) -> void;
    static auto solve() -> void;
};
```

We can still use a bare vector for the result… because that’s all the result is: just a vector.

Now we can implement the problem data like so:

```
class array_modification_problem
{
    std::vector<int> _data;
    int _pos;
    std::tuple<int, int> _rng;

public:
    // Input/output functions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    // Read problem data from stream.
    static auto read(std::istream& in) -> array_modification_problem;

    // Write solution to stream.
    static auto write(std::vector<int> const& data, std::ostream& out) -> void;

    // Actual solution function ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    static auto solve(array_modification_problem const& problem_data) -> std::vector<int>;

    // Nicer interface functions to simplify the above ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    static auto solve(std::istream& in) -> std::vector<int>;
    static auto solve(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) -> void;
    static auto solve() -> void;

    // Constructor for problem data ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    // this doesn't *need* to be public; you *could* make it private, but
    // since it is safe (assuming you do the checks mentioned below), it's
    // okay to make it public; it will make testing easier (because you can
    // create problem test data directly, without needing to put it in a
    // stream and parse it)
    array_modification_problem(std::vector<int> data, int position, std::tuple<int, int> range)
        : _data{std::move(data)}
        , _pos{position}
        , _rng{range}
    {
        // here we could check that the position and range values are okay
        // (like, that all the values are in range for the data vector),
        // and if not, throw an exception
    }
};
```

Now, what you’re concerned about—instantiating an object of the class within one of the static functions—is not a problem at all. That’s basically what all of the “nicer interface” functions above are doing. It is *possible* to instantiate an object of the class outside of those static functions either using `read()` or the constructor… but it doesn’t have to be; we could make those functions private, and everything would still be just fine (the class would just become a little less flexible).

(Performance-wise, there’s one small problem: The vector of numbers doesn’t get reused, so a whole new vector has to be created for the result. This is an easy fix, though; just add an overload of `solve()` that takes the problem data by rvalue reference, and then you can steal the vector out of it. But really getting into the performance weeds here will just add complications unrelated to the questions you’re interested in.)

So the above is basically what *I* would do if I were writing this. As you can see, it’s pretty darn close to what you did! But there are some very important differences, that I really think need to be pointed out. So let’s look at your version.

The first problem I have with your version—other than that I think the name `File` is bad—is that the class is *default-constructible*… and the default constructed data is illegal. That’s… pretty bad. In a well-written class, it should *never* be possible to create an illegal state (at least not without doing something incredibly stupid). Your class creates an illegal state *by default*.

And why is it illegal? Well, in the default constructed class, `eraseEle`, the position for the single element erasure, is 0. But… the numbers in the problem are 1-based. 0 is just plain illegal.

It turns out, though, that this isn’t actually a problem, because, for example, the `erase1()` function doesn’t even use `eraseEle`; it takes the position to erase as an argument.

Except… that creates an entirely new problem. Because a user of the class can pass literally *any* integer to `erase1()`. They can pass 0. Or −1. Literally *anything*.

So the *second* problem I have with your version is: all of your intermediate operation functions should be private. There is no reason to give J Rando User the power to call `erase1()` directly. That’s just inviting them to screw something up.

Note that the problem isn’t that you’ve made all the intermediate steps into functions. That’s fine; I know I didn’t do that above, but maybe I *should* have. I could have done something more like this:

```
private:
    auto erase_1()
    {
        _data.erase(_data.begin() + (_pos - 1));
    }

    auto erase_range()
    {
        _data.erase(_data.begin() + (std::get<0>(_rng) - 1), _data.begin() + (std::get<1>(_rng) - 1));
    }

public:
    static auto solve(array_modification_problem problem_data)
    {
        problem_data.erase_1();
        problem_data.erase_range();
        return problem_data._data;
    }
```

That’s fine because `erase_1()` and `erase_range()` are private, so I don’t need to check that the arguments are valid. I *do* need to check that they’re valid in the public function, though… except that’s already handled in the constructor. So everything is safe. It’s impossible to screw up. `array_modification_problem` is *always* created with valid data (or the constructor will throw), and so you can never call `solve()` with bad data, and thus it should always return valid results.

This probably isn’t the best way to do this, though, because after the first step, the problem data is now messed up. It’s okay *here*, because the messed up data is isolated within the `solve()` function. But you need to be careful if you ever refactor the class. It’s a bad idea to write functions that leave your class in an illegal state, even if they’re only used internally. That’s why I’d prefer to just do the two steps inline in `solve()`, with no help from other functions. Your mileage may vary.

There are plenty of other issues that arise from making these intermediate step functions public, too. For example, consider what would happen if someone called `processData()` twice. (This isn’t such a crazy idea. Someone might be solving these problems in a loop, and they might want to reuse the object.)

There are only a few other small things to mention:

1. `size` is pointless. `v` knows what size it is. All the effort you go through to keep `size` in sync with `v.size()` is error-prone and wasteful.
2. All four of the accessor functions are pointless. There is no reason to give users access to the internals of the class.
3. Also regarding the accessors: Returning `const` values is (almost) always wrong. It doesn’t really help anything—the user can strip away the `const` effortlessly.
4. In all the other functions *except* the accessors: The final `return;` statement is pointless.
5. In `processData()`: `temp` should not be declared at the top of the function. It should be declared right where you need it. (Which is right before `std::cin >> temp;`.)
6. Also in `processData()`: After reading `size`, you know how big the vector is supposed to be. At that point, you should call `v.reserve(size);`. This will prevent repeated re-allocations as you push back the elements, which could be a *massive* speedup.

So in summary, I think your concern is unwarranted: your `solve()` function is implemented just fine. It’s everything else that I think is problematic:

- Never allow objects to be constructible in an illegal state. If there is a sane default state, use that. If there is no sensible default state—as is the case here—then don’t allow default construction.
- Never allow objects to be *left* in an illegal state. Every function that can change the object should leave it in a legal state.
- Don’t make functions public if the user should never be allowed to call them. In your case, most of the functions in your class are dangerous, because they either should *only* be called in certain situations (like you can *only* call `erase1()` *directly* after `processData()`), and/or they can only be called exactly once. Your public interface should be idiot-proof, as much as possible… so giving random users access to functions that are so finicky and dangerous is a recipe for disaster.
- Test your code. Learn how to test *properly*, and write your classes so they can be easily tested.

Comment: Originally I wanted it to only read and process std::cin, hence the File name, but its a larger point to thinking Top-down instead of bottom-up. Most of the public GET functions were for testing.

Getting more familiar with unit testing is a good next step, and making sure testing is as easy as possible.

To avoid making an illegal state, a try catch block in the constructor would be a safe bet. Otherwise, assuming solve() is invoked in a loop, wouldn't this always arrive in an illegal state. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Yes, throwing an exception is the proper way to handle invalid arguments to a constructor. So if there is no sane default state, there should be no default constructor… and all non-default constructors should check their arguments to make sure they’re valid, and throw if not.

Comment: If you write all of your class’s public member functions so that none of them ever leaves the object in an invalid state—as you **ALWAYS** should—then there will be no problem calling `solve()` or any other member function in a loop. This is the problem with `File`; of the 4 (non-getter) member functions, only `print()` *always* leaves the object in a valid state (assuming, of course, it was in a valid state to begin with). `processData()` is okay if and only if the data being read is okay. The other two *always* leave the object in an invalid* state.

Comment: (\*Technically `erase1()` and `eraseRange()` don’t leave the object in a *completely* invalid state. They each leave the object in a state that is valid *only* for the very narrow set of purposes you intend. Like `eraseRange()` leaves it in a state where *only* calling `print()` or the destructor are valid (or, I suppose, overwriting it by calling `processData()`); you generally can’t call `eraseRange()` twice, and you can’t call `erase1()` after. So, *technically* not *completely* invalid… but still not good.)

Comment: “`processData()` is okay if and only if the data being read is okay.” Ah, actually this is wrong. I realized later that I forgot that `processData()` just keeps appending stuff to the end of `v`… so you can only call it *once*. If you call it twice, your object is (probably) corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

My feedback.

I would think about this as 'smart vector' - ie a vector with a few extra operations. IN this case just one.

I would never put IO in that class, except maybe the >> and << operators

I would look at how I would want it to behave first.

```
 SmartVector v;
 v.add(1);
 v.add(2);
 v.add(3);
 v.add(42);
 v.smartErase(2,4);
 for(int i = 0; i< v.size(); i++) {
     std::cout << v[i] << '\n';
 }

 // maybe this too
 std::cout << v << '\n';
```

implementing like this will give you experience in implementing

- operator <<
- operator []

this separates the vector manipulation from the IO. In your code the only way you could use you code was by reading it from std::cin

later you can set it up so that it reads from stdin

```
  int main(){
      SmartVector v;
      // load it
      int temp = 0;
      std::cin >> size;
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          std::cin >> temp;
          v.add(temp);
       }
    }
    // etc
```